# Php multidimensional array sort by column of other array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have first array of ids:

```
$ids = [10,12,8];
```

And I have array of data:

```
$arr = [
        12=>[
            'content'=>'test1'
        ],
        10=>[
            'content'=>'test2'
        ],
        8=>[
            'content'=>'test3'
        ]
    ];
```

How can I sort array `$arr` by `$ids` values, so as result I need have this:

```
 $arr = [
        10=>[
            'content'=>'test2'
        ],
        12=>[
            'content'=>'test1'
        ],
        8=>[
            'content'=>'test3'
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: `$sorted = array_replace(array_flip($ids), $arr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$ids = [10,12,8];
$arr = [
    "12" => ['content' => 'test1'],
    "10" => ['content' => 'test2'],
    "8" => ['content' => 'test3']
];
$result = array();
foreach($ids as $key){
    if(array_key_exists($key,$arr)){
        $result[$key] = $arr[$key];
    }
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

Happy coding